# Synchronous use of Mongo-Scala Driver

Tags: scala, asynchronous, mongodb

The [Mongo-Scala Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.6/getting-started/quick-tour/) (v2.6) currently only supports asynchronous operations, although my use cases often seem to lend themselves well to synchronous reads. This may be to block downstream code execution, or to save off the result-set of documents for later use. I'm guessing there may be a way to do this with Futures, but my current implementation doesn't utilize them.

At the moment, I use the following function to perform "synchronous" reads and return a list of documents. It serves my needs of blocking downstream code execution and returning a reusable list of documents, but it doesn't feel like the *cleanest* way to approach the problem - the use of `var` in Scala, and `while()` loops with a `Thread.sleep()` just feel like bandaids for a better solution. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// This is the code I'm looking for feedback on

import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

/* This function optionally takes filters if you do not wish to return the entire collection.
 * Future implementation may include optional {Sorts, Projections, Aggregates}
 */
def getDocsSync(db: MongoDatabase, collectionName: String, filters: Option[conversions.Bson]): ListBuffer[Document] = {
    val docs = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Document]()
    var processing = true
    val query = if (filters.isDefined) { // conditionally apply filters
        db.getCollection(collectionName).find(filters.get)
    } else {
        db.getCollection(collectionName).find()
    }
    query.subscribe(
        (doc: Document) => docs.append(doc), // add doc to mutable list
        (e: Throwable) => throw e, // handle errors here
        () => processing = false // deontes that we've reached the end of the collection
    )
    while (processing) {
        Thread.sleep(100) // wait here until all docs have been returned
    }
    docs
}
```

```
// sample usage of 'synchronous' query
val client: MongoClient = MongoClient(uriString)
val db: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase(dbName)
val allDocs = getDocsSync(db, "myCollection", Option.empty)
val someDocs = getDocsSync(db, "myCollection", Option(Filters.eq("fieldName", "foo")))
```

For reference, I'll include a typical asynchronous usage pattern for the Mongo-Scala Driver. As a quick note, I'd like to point out that I use this pattern whenever possible since it doesn't require the entire collection to be loaded into memory, which makes async a must for large collections.

```
// typical asynchronous usage pattern
db.getCollection(collectionName).find().subscribe(
    (doc: org.mongodb.scala.bson.Document) => {
        // operate on an individual document here
    },
    (e: Throwable) => {
        // do something with errors here, if desired
    },
    () => {
        // deontes that we've reached the end of the collection
    }
)
```